# Delphi equivalent to PHP's password_verify() function

Tags: delphi, password-hash, delphi-10.3-rio

Is there a "simple" function in Delphi (using 10.3 Professional) that allows me to verify a password with a hash code generated in PHP using [`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/password_hash)? A function which does the same as PHP's [`password_verify($password, $hash)`](https://www.php.net/password_verify)?

Example using PHP:

```php
$hash = password_hash('thisismyaccesscode', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
// $hash == '$2y$10$21qire0Qwz/gj6HEej3tf.skdiZzeB.rgFdg7qD.5rAhE/AFg.U8q'
```

Now I'm looking for a Delphi function, that tells me, if the password entered into my program can be verified against this hash.

Background: I have a list of user records for my web server. Using a web service I can retrieve a user's password hash from that server. I know it is generated using the PHP function `password_hash()`. I want to enable my users to log in to my Delphi program using the access code from the web site. Therefore I get the password hash from the web server and want to verify it locally in my Delphi program instead of uploading the password to the server and checking with PHP.

Comment: Seems unlikely to me...probably easier to write a little webservice in PHP which Delphi can check against.

Comment: No, there isn't. As per [compatibility projects](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) you can try building it yourself, starting to [support _Bcrypt_](https://github.com/JackTrapper/bcrypt-for-delphi) at first. Otherwise secure the web service's transport (TLS) if you're concerned about passwords being sent.

Comment: In the mean time I found a BCrypt Delphi library that does what I need: https://github.com/JackTrapper/bcrypt-for-delphi 
It's very simple to implement: just add bcrypt.pas to the uses list. The class TBCrypt contains a class function TBCrypt.CheckPassword.
My call is 
PWOK := TBCrypt.CheckPassword(KeyedInPwd, PWHashFromWebDB, BooleanDummy);
Does what I expected. - Thanks, JackTrapper!

Comment: @HeinziTuberkel Glad you found something that helps you. But that should be posted as an Answer, not a comment! Then a) people can find it by searching (comments are not searchable) and b) you can receive upvotes for it if people like it :-)

Answer (score 2):

I found a [BCrypt Delphi library](https://github.com/JackTrapper/bcrypt-for-delphi) that does what I need.
It's very simple to implement: just add `bcrypt.pas` to the uses list.

The class `TBCrypt` contains only class functions.
The `TBCrypt.CheckPassword` does what I need: input password and hash (I learned, that the hash string, I showed in my question contains the "salt").
My password check is something like:

```
PWOK := TBCrypt.CheckPassword(KeyedInPwdString, PWHashStringFromWebDB, BooleanDummy);
```

Answer (score 1):

The algorithms used by the PHP function "password_hash()" return different hashes for the same string, because their calculations depends on the used salt and the cost defined by the developer and also the server hardwares (the cost must be high enough so as the function will calculate in the desired time depending on the hardware capacities). So the algorithm must run with the same salt and parameters on the same device (if you optimize your hardware then you have to tune the cost to get the same efficiency, and set a migration process) in order to return the same hash.

In this case, the verification against the hash must occur on the server-side, and you have to send passwords as plain text in requests to the server where you implement a web service to verify passwords. You will have to use HTTPS and work on securing the transportations.

If your server is developed in PHP, you can use the function "password_verify()" for verifing against hashes generated by "password_hash().
But if your server is developed in Delphi, then there is no ready-to-use verification function. You have to use the Delphi port for the algorithm you used, then you implement a function for verifying the passwords (wrapping the hashing algorithm and string verification with the stored hash).

Comment: `never send passwords in HTTP requests as a plain text`...web applicatons do this all the time. They just use HTTPS to ensure the entire request data, including the password, cannot be intercepted or modified in transit. It's not a problem. PHP's password_verify() function compares a _plain text_ password against the hashed password stored on the server. This is standard practice and considered entirely secure.

Comment: `if you used MD5, SHA1 or SHA2`...let's hope not on the whole, because MD5 and SHA1 are considered insecure and inadequate these days, and they aren't used by php's password_hash() - the OP is hoping to be able to use a Delphi function to verify a password generated by that function. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php lists the algorithms which could have been used to hash the password in PHP

Comment: `Your client-side send the hashed password, along with other credentials (email or user id), in a REST request to your PHP script. Then on the server-side, you get the hashed password and compare it with the stored string in your database`...this shows a misunderstanding of how hashing works. Hashing the same string repeatedly will not always result in the same hash string, so a simple string comparison is insufficient. Hence why password_verify exists in PHP, and why it accepts a plain-text password from the user side.

Comment: `your client-side download the user corresponding hashed password (stored in your database)`...no, that should _never ever_ leave the server. Send password to the server in plain text (over an encrypted connection), let the server do the comparison and return a value to indicate if the user was authenticated or not.

Comment: Demo of the same plain-text string resulting in multiple different hash strings: https://3v4l.org/1MmUX . This is why I suggested in the comments that the simplest thing would be to build a little PHP API which any client-side app can call to check the login status. That way it always uses the PHP hashing functions to create and verify the passwords, rather than having to try and replicate such functions in Delphi (or anything else), and avoiding any of the insecure and/or unworkable proposals contained in this answer.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting comments. Even if PHP has those password functions, and password transport as plain text was standardized, it won't garanty more security than what you qualify as insecure propositions in our answer, not to mention that authenticating on a binary installed app is not the same as on a website.
Otherwise, it won't be necessary to invent or use salted hashed or OAuth or tokens systems.
So you can gamble on transporting passwords as plain text and jeopardize the project.

Comment: `authenticating on a binary installed app is not the same as on a website`... it pretty much is, if you're calling a web API to perform the authentication checks. What do you see as being the differences? Transporting the password in plain text isn't much of a gamble if you're using a secure communications channel. `it won't be necessary to invent or use salted hashed or OAuth or tokens systems`...why, exactly? These are all used commonly with web applications. A web app in a browser and a binary on the desktop are not so different, when the both talk to the server for authentication.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, we have corrected our response

Comment: Thanks. I don't think it needs to run on the same device as where the password was created, in order to verify it or generate the same hash, but it does certainly need the same salt you're right. This version of your answer is much better and more useful - your edit is appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing in the "server hardwares" influencing the ouput of the hash function. It is salted randomly by default so it's of course not deterministic. However, the salt is returned in the output together with the hash, as you can clearly read in the documentation: *"The used algorithm, cost and salt are returned as part of the hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included in it."*

Comment: Yes the server hardware can affect the functionning of the BCrypt, if you optimize your hardware without tuning the cost then your passwords will be hashed (and decrypted) faster. So the verification must run on the same device where the hashes were created and stored with the same cost. Otherwise, if you change the device (the server hardware), then you have to tune the cost to keep the same performance (and set a migration process).

Comment: That's a "could" rather than a "must" then, because it's about performance, not functionality. If you did it on a different machine then, based on your explanation, it might simply be faster or slower, not different.

Comment: P.S. `in order to return the same hash.`...but returning the same hash is not a useful objective, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the docs, the string returned by PHP's `password_hash` has a format. If your hashes start by `$2y`... then you could also understand (reimplement) the PHP `password_hash` function as follows (still in PHP):

```
$salt = base64_encode($random_string_of_22_characters_in_length);
$salt = str_replace('+', '.', $salt);
$hash = crypt('supers3cretpassword', '$2y$10$'.$salt.'$');
```

That brings you one step further to a Delphi port because [`crypt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) is an implementation of the standard UNIX DES-based algorithm, for which you will easily find Delphi implementations. A quick google returned [TUnixCrypt](https://appcontrols.com/manuals/unixcrypt/) but I am sure there are others. From its documentation:

> ... It works exactly as `crypt(key, salt)` Unix command

... which is your missing link. You would only need to parse the salt from within the hash from your server and produce a new hash with that and the user password.

Be aware that the original password could be in a different character encoding to start with, Make sure you encode your password accordingly or non-ascii passwords would fail to verify.